# How to get generated id from server right after submit form (post method) in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, post, get

I have a long-way-form to be filled so I dont want to lose any data after click on submit button. User will stay at the same page in case he wants to changes anything after submit. I want to get the id generated from server after submit button so that it will only update data based on that id instead of creating new id. Link below is my service and html.

[service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bn1NH.png)
[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RB8HT.png)

Below is my typescript

```
onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    if (form.value.projectproposalid == null) {
      this.projectService.postProposal(form.value)
        .subscribe(data => {
          this.projectService.selectedproposal.projectproposalid = data.projectproposalid;
          this.toastr.success('New Record Added Succcessfully', 'Your Proposal Registered');
        });
    }
    else {
      this.projectService.putProposal(form.value.projectproposalid, form.value)
        .subscribe(data => {
          this.toastr.info('Record Updated Successfully!', 'Your Proposal Updated');
        });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Post code of your http request along with response you are getting

Comment: hi Mas, just send data on response.

Comment: @Jamshed I can see the response data there but dont know how to access them.. Im really new to angular and still searching for the answer elsewhere :'(

Answer (score 0):

found a question that similar to my situation :) Thanks to @ketan__akbari

[Access http.post() response data from outside the method in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44623120/access-http-post-response-data-from-outside-the-method-in-angular-2)